# gstreamer: output window was closed

Tags: linux, media, gstreamer

I am suffering from the following error when I use gstreamer:

```
bus_call: bus_call(error) from /GstPlayBin2:player/GstPlaySink:playsink0/GstBin:vbin/GstFluVAAutoSink:fluvaautosink0/GstFluVAx11Sink:fluvax11sink0

bus_call: Error: Output window was closed

Debug details: fluvabasesink.c(874): gst_fluvabasesink_show_frame (): /GstPlayBin2:player/GstPlaySink:playsink0/GstBin:vbin/GstFluVAAutoSink:fluvaautosink0/GstFluVAx11Sink:fluvax11sink0
```

After my research, I think it is related to calling `gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id()`. When I remove calling this function, everything works fine though the video is just played in a new window instead of the given window.

But to `gst_x_overlay_set_xwindow_id()` , I check that overlay and window values are valid.

Do you have any suggestions on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this, too.  Someone told me that calling `gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle()` instead may result in differing behavior.

Comment: I tried this but failed again. But thanks all the same

Comment: Hey... when are you setting the handle?  Do you set it immediately in response to a "prepare-xwindow-id" notification (in 0.10, that is... "prepare-window-handle" in 1.x)?

Answer (score 0):

### Gstreamer 1.0

Bus Callback

```
void bus_cb(GstBus * bus, GstMessage * msg, gpointer user_data)
{
  gchar* messageInfo;
  const GstStructure *st = gst_message_get_structure(msg);

  auto pPipe = (VideoPipeline*)user_data;
  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg))
  {
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
    {
      g_main_loop_quit(pPipe->mLoop);
    }
    break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
    {
      GError *err = nullptr;
      gchar *dbg = nullptr;
      gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &dbg);
      //---------------------------------------------------------
            CHECK IF WINDOWS CLOSED BY MESSAGE
      //---------------------------------------------------------
      if (strstr(err->message, "Output window was closed"))
      {
         std::cout << "\r\nClosed\r\n";
         g_main_loop_quit(mLoop);
         return;

      }
      gst_object_default_error(msg->src, err, dbg);
      g_clear_error(&err);
      if (dbg != nullptr)
         g_free(dbg);
      break;
   }
   default:
    break;
  }
}
```